# SLACK BOLT PYTHON - Although the app should be installed into this workspace, the AuthorizeResult (returned value from authorize) for it was not found

Tags: python, slack, bolt, bolts-framework, slack-bolt

I want to build a simple Slack bolt python project so I followed this [document](https://slack.dev/bolt-python/tutorial/getting-started).
but when I use ***python_dotenv*** and then run my main file (app.py) I face this error:

```
As `installation_store` or `authorize` has been used, `token` (or SLACK_BOT_TOKEN env variable) will be ignored.

Although the app should be installed into this workspace, the AuthorizeResult (returned value from authorize) for it was not found.
```

**NOTE:** by deleting this line in the main file (app.py):

> load_dotenv()

and use the **export** method for defining tokens, everything works correctly.

this is my main file:

```
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from slack_bolt import App
from slack_bolt.adapter.socket_mode import SocketModeHandler
import logging

load_dotenv() # by deleting this file, the error will be gone, but I want using the dotenv pip


app = App(token=os.environ.get("SLACK_BOT_TOKEN"))
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

@app.message("hello")
def message_hello(message, say):
    # say() sends a message to the channel where the event was triggered
    say(f"Hey there <@{message['user']}>!")


# Start your app
if __name__ == "__main__":
    SocketModeHandler(app, os.environ["SLACK_APP_TOKEN"]).start()
```

Comment: Seems like this issue might've been brought up before. Might help to take a look at this: https://github.com/slackapi/bolt-python/issues/664

Comment: the problem still persists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know exactly why, but I removed extra keys in the .env file, and everything went fine.

in .env file:
**before:**

```
SLACK_APP_TOKEN=xapp-fake-token

SLACK_BOT_TOKEN=xoxb-fake-token

USER_TOKEN=xoxp-fake-token

SLACK_CLIENT_ID=aa.bb

SLACK_CLIENT_SECRET=YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET

SLACK_API_TOKEN_APP_LEGACY=xoxb-fake-token

SLACK_SIGNING_SECRET=YOUT_SIGNING_SECRET
```

**after:**

```
SLACK_APP_TOKEN=xapp-fake-token

SLACK_BOT_TOKEN=xoxb-fake-token
```

Comment: Idk why, but same happened to me. It wasn't working till I removed SLACK_CLIENT_ID and SLACK_CLIENT_SECRET